# Video does not display on Iphone unless I run the Iphone simulator first in xcode

Tags: ios

In place of the video there is a little quicktime symbol instead. If you tap on the symbol only the audio plays. My video works perfectly on the app if I run the iphone simulator before putting the app on an iPod touch.

I plugged my video in my app by plugging html into my Localizable.strings file:

```
"login help" = "<embed src=\"rabbit1.MOV\">";
```

This is how I access the Localizable.strings file:

```
    if ([_topic isEqualToString:@"How do I login?"]){

    // set help text
    NSString *key = @"login help";
    NSString *helpText;
    if (helpText == nil)
    {
        // fetch text from resources
        helpText = NSLocalizedString(key, nil);

    }

    title = @"How do I login?";
    _topic = helpText;

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [SCServerAPI getHelpMessageForKey:_topic forSuccess:^(NSString *html) {
        [_webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
    } forError:nil];

}
```

Why does this happen? Anyway to fix it?

Comment: are those quotes a mistake or is your code actually written that way?

Comment: my code is actually written that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help. I think I've found my problem. I was missing the width and height attributes in my html.

Example:

```
"startup help" = "<br><br><embed src=\"rabbit1.MOV\" height=\"300\" width=\"300\">";
```

Now I see the thumbnail and it plays audio AND video. =]

Answer (score 0):

Just quick idea because of absence of code. It's possible there is problem with case sensitivity. Check the filename extension if you really have MOV in uppercase.